# $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$ versus $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(a+x)$

Tags: limits, notation

Just had a quick question about the variable naming observed in the following statement:

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$

Is the above statement equivalent to:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(a+x) \quad ?$

If so, is there any particular reason to prefer the former over the latter? Cheers~

Comment: The only difference is in the "voice" of the writer.  In a similar way, the inequalities $a < b$ and $b > a$ are logically equivalent, but they allow the writer to alter in how it's read (e.g. placement of emphasis,  etc)

Comment: If you dare, you can also use $\widetilde{\Xi_a^*}$ instead of $h$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is the variable associated with the $\to$ beneath the limit effectively being universally quantified over (when one interprets this formally)? ...I assume that's why any name will work just fine.

Comment: @Hagen ... and be pilloried by everyone who reads it ;-).  Even though some claim mathematics is 100% objective, pragmatics and respect still are important...

Comment: There is nothing subjective about this. Any reasonable person would use $h$ and I stand will stand by this.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: isn't this symbol reserved for the conversion factor from furlongs per fortnight to parsecs per blink ?

Comment: The variable which occurs below the limit notation is a *dummy* variable and part of the notation. You can replace a dummy variable by another. This is not substitution, not change of variables, nothing big, but just the way limit notation works. Maybe in your high school algebra you solved some questions like "two consecutive integers sum up to 7, find the smaller one" starting with "let the smaller integer be $x$". It does not matter if you choose the smaller number as $t$.

Comment: And while we are talking about limits, you can replace $\epsilon, \delta$ by $e, d$ in entire definition (except perhaps you will have to mention explicitly that $e$ here is not the base of natural logarithm).

Answer (score 3):

They are the same thing, and I would write one or the other indistinctly. The reason to prefer the first one would be the desire to stress over a change of variable.

Comment: Thank you! If you're willing, could you please elaborate on your final statement? - "...to stress over a change of variable"?

Comment: @S.Cramer Nothing really to elaborate about: you've made a change of variable, therefore some people like to use a different letter for the new variable.

Comment: Sorry, I am asking about *what* the change of variable would be in the above case. You commented on the "second one" (which uses $x$ instead of $h$). I'm not sure I understand how to specify the change of variable here.

Comment: @S.Cramer It was a typo, however, the change of variable to obtain the first from the seond would be the inverse function of the change of variables used to obtain the second from the first.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate what this change of variable would be? I'm not sure I understand what a "change of variable" is in this context. When I see things like $f(a+x)$, I immediately convert them to new functions (e.g. $g(x)=f(a+x)$).

Answer (score 2):

The first form is safer, as it uses distinct variables for the absolute and relative positions, hence avoids confusions.

(A second argument is that "by tradition", $h$ is immediately recognized as a relative displacement.)